# Is an eigen recognition model picklable?

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing, eigen

I have a python-based face recognition script running several processes (threads?) all doing different things. I am attempting to use one of these to re-train the model once the training images have been changed/updated.

I have tried sending the model through the python pipe function:

```
pipe.send(model)
```

I am not hit with any exceptions, it just hangs there indefinitely.

I fear that either the model is either unpicklable, or simply just too big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` (or `cPickle`, depending on the version).  Have you tried checking like this?

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pik = pickle.dumps(model)
>>> _model = pickle.loads(pik)
```

If that succeeds, it's serializable by `pickle`.  If it's not, you might try using a more powerful serializer, and a fork of `multiprocessing` that utilizes said better serializer (i.e. `dill` and `pathos.multiprocessing`).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tested script you supplied and got:

    TypeError: can't pickle FaceRecognizer objects

Not the outcome I was hoping for, but it answers the question. I will look into using the stronger serializers.

Cheers!